# Setting the propery, when not knowing which one

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Say I have this class with a few members, for example (this is a contrived example, I'd rather no have a discussion about the intricacies of the real-life design. I really just want to convey the general idea here.):

```
public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? HouseId { get; set; }
    public Guid? FlatId { get; set; }
    public Guid? SomeOtherBuildingTypeId { get; set; 
}
```

Now as it happens there exist 3 methods to create an Address:

```
public void CreateAddressForHouse();
public void CreateAddressForFlat();
public void CreateAddressForSomeOtherBuildingType();
```

Under the surface this group of methods does the exact same thing, bar setting a different Id property in the Address class. This is causing quite some code duplication in the real life application and I want to rewrite this to something more general.

In my mind I can pass the name of the required property and its value to a CreateAddress function, in something like a Func. But I'm seriously lacking in this respect, where to start? What .NET stuff can I use out of the box? Or what specific keywords should I look for?

Comment: Pack everything the methods do "exactly [the] same" into a separate method `CreateAddress()` (probably `private`) and call that from those three methods? Or better yet, have one `Guid BuildingTypeID` and one `BuildingType BuildingType` being a value of the `enum BuildingType { House, Flat, SomethingElse, YetAnotherThing }`, which seems far more flexible than a new property for every new type of building.

Comment: I'm not happy with this property-per type, it's a result of having some tables with a lot of nullable FKs :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a MemberExpression:

```
public void CreateAddress(Expression<Func<Address, Guid?>> member)
{
    // Get the property from the expression
    var propertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(this, member);

    // Create a new address
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();

    // Assign it to the property of this instance
    propertyInfo.SetValue(this, guid);
}
```

Then you call the method like this, using a lambda `a => a.PropertyName`:

```
var address = new Address();
address.CreateAddress(a => a.HouseId);
Console.WriteLine(address.HouseId);
```

See [Retrieving Property name from lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression) for the implementation of `GetPropertyInfo`. It gets the `PropertyInfo` of the member specified in the lambda expression (and checks that it is indeed a property), which you can use to set the property in the `CreateAddress` method.

Apart from that, [@Corak's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179793/setting-the-propery-when-not-knowing-which-one#comment52245234_32179793) is a valid one. Maybe you shouldn't use a property per address type, but use a `Dictionary<AddressType, Guid?>` property. That may or may not be viable depending on the class design and its intended usage.

Comment: I wish I could, but this is a direct result of having some tables with a lot of nullable FKs.

Comment: By using this I've managed to refactor & centralize a lot of duplicate code in various cases! Spent a few days writing tests & refactoring and this really helped alot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use expression trees to simplify your problem:

```
public class AddressService
{
    public Address CreateAddress(Expression<Func<Address, Guid?>> idPropertySelector)
    {
        // So you get the property info to later set it using reflection
        MemberExpression propertyExpr = (MemberExpression)idPropertySelector.Body;
        PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)propertyExpr.Member;

        // Then you create an instance of address...
        Address address = new Address();

        // and you set the property using reflection:
        property.SetValue(address, (Guid?)Guid.NewGuid());

        return address;
    }
}
```

Now, who knows where in your code, this will work:

```
AddressService service = new AddressService();
Address address = service.CreateAddress(a => a.FlatId);
Guid? flatId = address.FlatId; // This will be already assigned!
```

Comment: This (`(MemberExpression)idPropertySelector.Body`) will throw when called with `a => new Guid()` (or anything that isn't a MemberExpression, basically).

Comment: @CodeCaster Sometimes I feel that SO answers shouldn't fit all use cases nor pay attention to all side effects. At the end of the day, we're not a coding service... If the OP gets the idea, it's enough. What's your opinion?

Comment: You're absolutely right. We don't have to provide fool-proof, copy-pasteable code. I just commented it as a warning. This code is not user-friendly nor should it be used as-is (at least, if you care about (re)usability and relevant exceptions when using the code wrong). But that goes for most code on SO. :-)

Comment: Very nice stuff this Expression api. Should look into this :)

Comment: @CodeCaster That bullet-proof code should be on some GitHub repository or who knows. At the end of the day, at least for me, SO is a bunch of ideas to get some direction to learn more about some topic. I don't like providing full solutions with all details, because you need some challengue to go beyond your own knowledge and skills, and copy-paste solutions aren't for this

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property BuildingType BuildingType being a value of the enum BuildingType { House, Flat, SomeOtherBuildingType, YetAnotherThing } as suggested by Corak.
To make it simpler, you can create a parameterized constructor in Address class:

```
public Address(Guid? id,BuildingType type)
{
 switch(type)
 {
  case BuildingType.House:
                   HouseId=id;
                   break; 
  case BuildingType.Flat:
                   FlatId=id;
                   break;
  case BuildingType.SomeOtherBuildingType:
                   SomeOtherBuildingTypeId =id;
                   break;
  default:
        break;
 }
}
```

This way it will be easier to extend.
Also, you need not to have so many methods. Only one CreateAddress() can be used to generate address of multiple types.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid :)